# Custom id's in javascript created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am working on a jeopardy web app and I have a portion of the app where players can create as many teams as they need and give them a custom name.

HTML

```
<!--Score Boards-->
        <div id="teamBoards">
                <div id="teams">

                </div>
                <div id="addTeams">
                    <h3>Add Teams</h3>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Team Name" id="teamName">
                    <button id="addTeam">Add a Team</button>
                </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "Teams"
    var teamNameElement = document.createElement("h3");
    var teamName = $('#teamName').val();
    teamNameElement.textContent = teamName;
    var score = document.createElement("h4");
    score.textContent = "0";
    score.id = "score"+teamName;
    score.className = "score";
    var plusButton = document.createElement("button");
    plusButton.textContent = "+";
    plusButton.id = "plus"+teamName;
    plusButton.className = "plus";
    var minusButton = document.createElement("button");
    minusButton.textContent = "-";
    minusButton.id = "minus"+teamName;
    minusButton.className = "minus";
    div.appendChild(teamNameElement);
    div.appendChild(score);
    div.appendChild(plusButton);
    div.appendChild(minusButton);
    var placementDiv = document.getElementById('teams');
    placementDiv.appendChild(div);
```

The code above creates a team name, a place for the score with 0 preset, and a plus and minus button for points.

I start to have trouble when I go to add or subtract points by 100.

JS

```
$(plusButton).on('click', add);
    $(minusButton).on('click', minus);

    function add(){
        var score1 = $('.score').html();
        console.log(score1);
        score1 = Number(score1);
        score1 = score1 + 100;
        console.log(score1);
        $(score).html(score1);
    }

    function minus(){
        var score1 = $('.score').html();
        score1 = Number(score1);
        score1 = score1 - 100;
        $(score).html(score1);
    }
```

All of the code here is in one function, so some variables from the plus and minus functions could be the variables from the code above. The problem is that I can not add points to specific teams' scoreboard through a specific id for each team score.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do what your looking at using more jQuery and $this selectors to work with individual teams like you want. I added some notes in the snippet below. Just run the snippet a few times and look at the comments to see how the teams are being selected.

```js
$(function(){
    var teamCount = 0;
    var $teamsDiv = $("#teams");

    $("#addTeam").click(function(){
        //get the team name value
        var teamName = $("#teamName").val();
        
        //Create clone of html team template
        var $newTeam = $("#teamTemplate").clone();
        //Set an id for each team using the teamCount var
        $newTeam.attr("id", "team" + teamCount);
        //Set the entered text
        $newTeam.find(".teamName").text(teamName);
        //Set the score to zero
        $newTeam.find(".score").text("0");
        
        //Append new team to teams div
        $teamsDiv = $("#teams");
        $teamsDiv.append($newTeam.html());
    });

    
    //Add button press (using $("#teams").on('click'... allows for setting
    //listeners on dynamically created html 
    $("#teams").on('click', '.plusButton', function() {
      var $teamTemplate = $(this).closest(".template");
      var $score = $teamTemplate.find(".score");
      var teamName = $teamTemplate.find(".teamName").text();
      var currentScore = parseInt($score.text());
      $score.text(currentScore + 100);
      
       $(this).closest(".template").find(".teamName");
      console.log(teamName + " Score: " + $score.text());
    })
    //Minus button press
    $("#teams").on('click', '.minusButton', function() {
      //Using the "this" selector edit just the div you want.
      var $teamTemplate = $(this).closest(".template");
      var $score = $teamTemplate.find(".score");
      var teamName = $teamTemplate.find(".teamName").text();
      var currentScore = parseInt($score.text());
      //Set new score text
      $score.text(currentScore - 100);
      
      //Console.log just to see what is happening
       $(this).closest(".template").find(".teamName");
      console.log(teamName + " Score: " + $score.text());
    })
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Score Boards-->
<div id="teamBoards">
    
    <div id="addTeams">
        <h3>Add Teams</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Team Name" id="teamName">
        <button id="addTeam">Add a Team</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="teams">

    </div>
</div>

<div style="display:none;" id="teamTemplate"  >
  <div class="template">
    <span class="teamName"></span>
    <button class="plusButton" type="button">+</button>
    <button class="minusButton">-</button>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="score">0</span>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

I would highly recommend the [Jquery video tutorial](http://try.jquery.com/) for getting a jump on using jQuery. It is a great tutorial that shows all the tricks to making client side code quick and easy.